# Google Prettify toggle linenums

Tags: jquery

I'm using Google Prettify and was wondering if it was possible to toggle the linenums class?

```
$('.hide').on('click',function(e){
        $('ol, pre').toggleClass('linenums');

    });
```

The above toggles the class but the linenumbers still show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you'll need something like:

```
$('.hide').on('click',function(e){
    $('ol.linenums li').toggleClass("nolinenums");
});
```

and have in your css something like

```
li.nolinenums 
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```